# I'm having this error in my app ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, rubygems, tdd

StandardError
Directly inheriting from ActiveRecord::Migration is not supported. Please specify the Active Record release the migration was written for:
class AddAttachmentImageToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
Extracted source (around line #596):

```
    major = ActiveRecord::VERSION::MAJOR
    minor = ActiveRecord::VERSION::MINOR
    raise StandardError, "Directly inheriting from ActiveRecord::Migration is not supported. " \
      "Please specify the Active Record release the migration was written for:\n" \
      "\n" \
      "  class #{subclass} < ActiveRecord::Migration[#{major}.#{minor}]"
```

Directly inheriting from ActiveRecord::Migration is not supported. Please specify the Active Record release the migration was written for:
class AddAttachmentImageToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
Extracted source (around line #596):

Comment: Are you setting up local environment for an old rails app? run `rake db:setup` or `rake db:schema:load`instead of running all the old migrations.

Comment: This error is shown, when you try running old migrations that were created with old version of Ruby on Rails with up-to-date versions. Follow the advice @BroiSatse gave, or you need to fix all old migrations to follow the conventions for current versions of Ruby on Rails.